Is it possible estimate depth classicaly between two frames?
Since stereo camera use two camera to capture two frames at a time, then intuitively we can just use monocular camera except we need difference between frames over time?
So, is it possible to do that?
Note: I'm not talking about any machine learning approach, instead I'm asking classical approach where the model is defined by human.
